# Is there any limit on number of devices you can install Apps on from Amazon App Store?

Tags: amazon-appstore

I recently started using the Amazon App store, and noticed that it copies the apps I already purchased or downloaded to other Android devices if I sign in using the same account. Is there any specified limit on the number of devices that this is supported on? If I have 10 Android devices can I buy an app once and install it on all of them?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Doubt I have 25 devices though. Anyone have the direct URL to list if devices? Mark

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, you can install all the apps you buy from the Amazon appstore on any device which is linked to that Amazon account.  It operates just like paid apps in the Android Market which are available to all the devices associated with that particular Google Account.

I have 3 Android devices and all they are all linked to the same Amazon account and the same Google account and when I purchase an app through the Market or the Appstore I have it on all three devices.

Answer (score 5):

The max is 25. It'll tell you that your username or password is wrong if you try to auth any more. Though it's pretty easy de-authing them from the amazon website

Found a source:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/archive/index.php/t-1315474.html

Comment: Sounds plausible, but can you point to any documentation that states this?

Comment: Nope, just personal experience. I often wipe my devices and accumulated 25 authorized devices whether they were still in use or not. I kept getting an err that my username and pwd were incorrect. That's when I began investigating and found this post. I never found anything to actually help me, I just logged into Amazon from the website, counted up my auth'd devices, and there was 25. Deleted the oldest, and sure enough, my latest device snyc'd up just fine.

Comment: I can second the device limit of 25 (personal experience). After many custom rom installs, I reached this limit and had to clear out a bunch of old devices.

Answer (score 3):

Applications purchased are tied to your Amazon account.  You can also tie multiple devices to your Amazon account.  However, every device must have the Amazon Appstore app installed on it and must be logged in to access the apps installed via the Amazon Appstore, which would give anyone with any of these devices the ability to purchase additional apps using your Amazon account and it's payment information.  So, as the [Amazon help](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200551840) describes it, it does look like it's possible.  However, it also looks like a really bad idea unless you absolutely trust everyone who has each of these 10 devices.